# OOP - ES6 - Node Js - Calling parent method from children function - SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here

Tags: node.js, oop, inheritance, foreach, ecmascript-6

When I try to ejecute this code on Node.Js fail. I have created completed code to everybody be able to see real results.

This is classes's structure :

FILE printlog.js

```
const echo  = require( 'node-echo'      );

class printlog
{
  p (msg)   {   echo(msg)      }
}

exports.printlog = printlog;
```

File B.js

```
var { printlog } = require('./printlog.js')

class B extends printlog
{
  constructor() {
    super()
  }


  a_works(pos,elem) {
    super.p(pos  + ' - ' + elem)
  }

  a_fail(a_passed) {
  if ( Array.isArray(a_passed) ) 
    a_passed.forEach( function(elem, pos, array) 
    {
            super.p(pos     + ' - ' + elem )   // fail
    })

  }
}

var c = new B()
var arr = [2000, 2001, 2003,2039, 2040]

c.a_works(10,3)   // works

c.a_fail(arr)  // fail
```

Node Js version :

```
node -v
v8.6.0
```

Node command

```
node B.js
```

This is the error :

```
/B.js:25
                super.p(pos     + ' - ' + elem )
                ^^^^^

SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:588:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:607:3
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I tested the code just change `echo()` ->  to `console.log()`
And Its works

---

```
class printlog
{

  p (msg)   {   console.log(msg)      }
}

class B extends printlog
{
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
  a(pos,elem) {
    super.p(pos  + ' - ' + elem)

  }
}
const bb = new B();
bb.a('pos', 'sss');
```

Answer (score 0):

Without all of your code, it's hard to guess what's wrong with it. I am assuming in your class constructor, you declare something like this.p = ''. Please provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't related to inheritance or other OOP issues.

What was failing is the method to iterate array, so seems using forEach we can't get other class methods (super , this )

If we change bucle by :

```
for (var i = 0; i < a_passed.length; i+=1)
```

Code works correctly.

Full Code :

File B.js

```
var { printlog } = require('./printlog.js')

class B extends printlog
{
  constructor() {
    super()
  }


  a_works(pos,elem) {
    super.p(pos  + ' - ' + elem)
  }

  a_dont_fail(a_passed) {
  if ( Array.isArray(a_passed) ) 
    for (var i = 0; i < a_passed.length; i+=1) 
    {
            super.p(i     + ' - ' + a_passed[i] )   // works
    })

  }
}

var c = new B()
var arr = [2000, 2001, 2003,2039, 2040]

c.a_works(10,3)   // works

c.a_dont_fail(arr)  // works
```

Thanks for read me.